# oracle table permission

Tags: c#, oracle

In Oracle, `MYTABLE` owner is `USER1` and assign permissions to `USER2`. But in the C# code, `USER2` still can't access the table.

If I use `USER1`, the owner, to query this table in C# code, it said:

> can not execute query

```
GRANTEE                      OWNER               TABLE_NAME       GRANTOR              PRIVILEGE                              GRANTABLE HIERARCHY 
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------------------------------------- --------- --------- 
USER2                       USER1                MYTABLE         USER1                DELETE                                   NO        NO        
USER2                       USER1                MYTABLE         USER1                SELECT                                   NO        NO        
USER2                       USER1                MYTABLE         USER1                UPDATE                                   NO        NO
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the error when User2 tries to query the table?  What is the exact query that User2 is issuing?

The most common problem is that User2 is not qualifying the table name with the schema name.  User2 would, by default, need to do something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM User1.MyTable
```

If you don't want to qualify the table name, you could either create a synonym in User2's schema for User1's MyTable

```
CREATE SYNONYM myTable
   FOR User1.MyTable
```

or you could create a public synonym (public synonyms are visible to all users though they have no impact on privileges)

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM myTable
   FOR User1.MyTable
```

or you can set the `current_schema` for the session after connecting

```
ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = User1
```

If you do any of these things, User2 would be able to run the query

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyTable
```

and have `MyTable` resolve to `User2.MyTable`.  The private synonym is the smallest footprint-- it applies only to User2 and only for `MyTable`.  The public synonym means that anyone that has been granted privileges on `User1.MyTable` would be able to query it without qualifying the table name with the schema name.  Changing the `current_schema` means that all unqualified object references in the future for that session will be resolved in the `User1` schema rather than the current user's schema.